# Pass stringified json object to php and access it

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, object

I'm trying to send a stringified json object to php and access it there after i decode it,but i can't manage to do that, what i receive in php is a null ... something :

JS:

```
var bruh = {id: "509", type: "14", sortorder: "0", status: "1", name: "Pop-up SaaS", title: "test", request: true};

serializedData = JSON.stringify(bruh);

request = $.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "JSON",
  data: serializedData
});

request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
  console.log("Hooray, it worked!"+response, textStatus, jqXHR);
});
```

PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$article = json_decode($_POST['data']); // $_POST['data'] is null don't know why
```

How do i know that $_POST is null? well i'm outputing the result and checking the response on my console.log , like this:

```
echo json_encode($_POST['data']);

echo json_encode($_POST);

echo json_encode($_POST[0]);

echo $_POST['data'];

print_r($_POST); //SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

The exact response i'm receiving is(via Firebug):

```
readyState  4
responseJSON  null
responseText  "null"
status  200
statusText  "OK"
```

Can anyone help me solve this please?

**UPDATE:** I also tried to send it like this:

serializedData = "{data:"+ JSON.stringify(bruh)+"}";

but still no result

Comment: You don't have `data` key in your POST. What really should be checked instead of all these `encodings` is `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I'm getting SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data if i do it that way

Comment: You need to check the __OUTPUT__ of your php script.

Comment: *if i do it that way*?? how about you don't do it *that* way and just do u_mulder's way, using the first js code

Comment: @u_mulder , and how exactly i'm doing that?

Comment: @u_mulder , in the chrome preview/response tab i get an empty array

Comment: @Xorifelse , 'using the first js code' ... i didn't get the reference , what js code?

Comment: Why not just send plain `bruh` object: `data: bruh`? What will change?

Comment: Don't use your update, only the first js code no changes. then the only thing you need to do is `echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: @u_mulder , because i need to access it in php so i have to json_decode it, but to do so,the parameter must be a string,that's why i JSON.stringify

Comment: @Xorifelse , i did , i just pasted them all to highlight the fact that all of those returned null/empty

Comment: You wouldn't believe it but if you pass your plain object as `data: bruh` it will still be accesible in php.

Comment: @u_mulder , no it doesn't , i tried. Still empty,but now i got the 'param must be string' error

Comment: __It does__. You just doing something __wrong__. Trying to `json_decode` a POST array maybe?

Comment: i'm sending the plain object , then json_decode($_POST); is something wrong here?

Comment: Yes, there's __NO NEED__ to decode anything.

Comment: and how you access the object? $_POST['id'] ??

Comment: @u_mulder , i don't understand..., it's not the first time i'm working with ajax/json , all the times i had to encode/decode why is it working now? Anyway, post an answer please so i can vote up/select.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
`data: serializedData` to `data: {'data': seralizedData},`

To confirm the post field 'data' is indeed being posted, you could inspect the headers using something like fiddler, or network tools built into most browsers.

In php check for the field:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){ 
    // other checks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When dataType is json, you have to use `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` in php file to grap submitted data. Then you can get data. Or you can remove dataType.

jQuery:

```
var bruh = {id: "509", type: "14", sortorder: "0", status: "1", name: "Pop-up SaaS", title: "test", request: true};
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: bruh,
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("Result " + data);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

In php you can use `$_POST`, need not json_decode.

```
echo $_POST['type']; // 14
```